# Query to find the average of the number of records per group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table having 2 Columns i.e FarmerName,PesticideUsed and Town.

1. How can i find the Average Number of Farmers Using A particular Pesticide.
2. Average Number of Farmers in Each Town

There are 29 unique Pesticides And 8 Unique Towns.

I tried to write the first one i.e

```
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "select count(FarmerName)/29 as average_count from try", con);
```

I dont think it is right.

How i am i going to do that....

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: Use a group by on Pesticide Used

Comment: @user1056466 are you sure you want to find Average Number of Farmers Using A particular Pesticide or the Number of Farmers Using A particular Pesticide or the average number of farmers using pesticide

Comment: You need to study about aggregate functions and the `GROUP BY` clause, to understand how to use the answer you've received

Comment: Also, a quick refresh on how to count to three might be useful ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Average number of farmers using a pesticide:

```
SELECT PesticideUsed ,AVG(num)
FROM (
SElECT PesticideUsed ,COUNT(*) as num
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY PesticideUsed) a
GROUP BY PesticideUsed
```

Average number of farmers per town:

```
SELECT town ,AVG(num)
FROM (
SElECT town ,COUNT(*) as num
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY town) a
GROUP BY  town
```

Answer (score -2):

try this instead.

adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "select AVG(FarmerName) as average_count from try", con);

Comment: You can not average a string.  Likely the farmers name is a string.